# Material UI MultiSelect Showing Selected Items Below Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, dropdown

As I wrote on the title, I want to display selected items below the dropdown. But it display them inside by default. It doesn't have to be multiple select but when I click on an item I want it to be pushed to an array and then I want to map through that array below dropdown.

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
              <InputLabel id="company">Şirket</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="company"
                name="company"
                id="company"
                label="Company"
                value={formik.values.company}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                sx={{ width: 300 }}
              >
                <MenuItem value="">
                  <em>None</em>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
              </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Comment: What component are you using? Can you show us the code and what you've done so far?

Comment: I added the code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected item should be stored in the state of your component. You can use this to map through the items and display them where you want. Have a look at this example code I created based in MUI sandbox example for the multiple select [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-demo-material-ui-forked-rkh80i?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But it displays the names twice

Comment: I edited the sandbox again. Before i had two versions to help you to understand more. For example I had a map loop which you were looping and you could change the styling and after that i was just displaying the names. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using formik to handle forms. How can I use a custom onChange with formik

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used formik before :( but from this example I googled they have an onChange event and you can use the material-ui components the same way (https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui)

Comment: how can i show already selected values inside dropdown? may be highlight background.

Comment: @Siri If I understand correct your question this is already covered in MUI selection component. Please create a question in stackoverflow with your code. Thanks

Comment: @Akis yes. found it. Thank you.